# Is holding a third citizenship allowed?

Tags: us-citizens, multiple-citizenship, turkey

I was born in California and automatically became a US citizen. I obtained the second nationality from my parents. Now I live in Turkey and the government offered me Turkish citizenship without asking me to renounce any previous ones. Are there any negative consquences for a US citizen in this scenario?

Comment: Third? USA, Turkey, and....?

Comment: In addition to the question of whether all three countries allow multiple citizenship, consider the accumulation of citizen obligations. You already have the US tax and foreign account reporting obligations of a US citizen, as well as all the obligations of a citizen of your parents' country. You may be adding obligations to Turkey.

Comment: E.g. [Vladimir Posner](https://en.0wikipedia.org/index.php?q=aHR0cHM6Ly9lbi53aWtpcGVkaWEub3JnL3dpa2kvVmxhZGltaXJfUG9zbmVy) is a citizen of US, France, and Russia. I'd say this depends on a country, I remember a few friends in Turkey mentioning their country (either Turkey or the other one) didn't allow double citizenships or some such.

Comment: @ouflak: Do not revert-war improving the question. The specific nationalities matter.

Comment: As the question can get several good answers without regards to the specific nationalities, there's no need specificy them in the title. However, if the OP wishes to do so, then I will leave that. Typically it is good form not to change the nature of the question with edits unless the OP makes that change..

Comment: @ouflak: "Is holding a third citizenship allowed?" makes no sense without knowing those specific nationalities and the requirements, obligations and conflicts those involve. I did not change the nature of the question. I merely added missing details to title. Typically it is always good form to change the title if doing so improves specificity or clarity. If you disagree, go read 10 years of meta posts.

Comment: @smci, ""Is holding a third citizenship allowed?" makes no sense without knowing those specific nationalities" - Not true. There are practically an infinite number of triple citizenship combinations possible in the world. The general answer is 'yes', but it's a broad question which the OP refines for his specific sitation in the main part of the question. If you wish to discuss this meta, that's fine. I don't see any problem with the subject question as-is or the main content. Also, I do not partake in 'revert wars'. Huge waste of time.

Comment: @smci, I merely rejected the edit as it potentially changed the subject to something which the OP did not at all intend. In other words, they may have wished to ask a generic question, as well as wanted a specific response for their situation, perhaps wanting answers for both the broad and specific question. Your edit changed that nature of that subject question, which is typically frowned upon. If the OP makes that change, I've got no problem with it. It's their question afterall.

Answer (score 12):

The US does not generally restrict its citizens from having other nationalities.  This doesn't depend on the number of other nationalities.

The same caveats that apply to dual nationality also apply, however.  Taking another nationality is one of the statutory "potentially expatriating acts," but one cannot be deprived of US citizenship involuntarily, so citizenship is retained unless the act is done with the intention of relinquishing citizenship.  The US generally presumes that no such intention exists.

You do not state what your other country of current citizenship is.  That country might have a law that would cause you to lose its citizenship if you naturalize in Turkey.

Answer (score 3):

Triple nationality is definitely possible.

My children have US citizenship (through their mother and their place of birth), UK citizenship (through me) and NZ citizenship (through naturalization).

Comment: Now you just need to move to South Korea and connect the globe.

Comment: Foreigners getting the South Korean citizenship have to renounce their foreign citizenship(s). Conversely, Koreans getting a foreign citizenship will lose their Korean citizenship. So South Korea won't be a very good choice.